# While loop with integers not working

Tags: c++, while-loop, integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int integer=400;
int count=1;

while (count == integer){
cout<< count<<endl;

count = count + 1;
}

}
```

This is basically what I used on my project. Seems to give no output. Help?

Comment: Have you ever tried [rubber duck debugging (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?  You should try it!

Comment: when the while loop evaluates the condition value of `count` variable is `1` and that of `integer` variable is `400`. The statement `count == integer` evaluates to false

Comment: Also, you should return an integer from the function if you have "int main"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count == integer` is evaluating false. I think you mean `while (count < integer)`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! It helped a lot.

Comment: How would I do a loop for a boolean format variable, if using == is evaluating false and cannot use < for a boolean format? I'm just so new to c++

Comment: use `==` or `!=` for boolean format

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the program to run a while loop with a false condition, i.e. you're comparing `count` and `integer`, of which the former's value is `1`, and the latter is set to `400`.
`(count == integer)` will return false, and the loop will simply be skipped over.

I think what you're trying to do is
        `while (count < integer)`
wherein the loop will start with `count` set to 1, and increased to 400 in increments of 1 (as per `count = count + 1;`).